Kamal Missing secret_key_base
I'm trying to deploy a Rails 8 application with Kamal 2.4 with the following deploy file.
service: appa

image: appa

servers:
  web:
    - 1.2.3.4
  job:
    hosts:
      - 1.2.3.4
    cmd: bin/jobs

proxy:
  ssl: true
  host: app.appa.dev

registry:
  server: ghcr.io
  username: appa
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

builder:
  arch: amd64

env:
  clear:
    POSTGRES_USER: rails
    POSTGRES_HOST: 1.2.3.4
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD

ssh:
  user: appa
  keys: [ "~/.ssh/appa" ]

accessories:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:17.2-alpine
    port: 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
    host: 1.2.3.4
    env:
      clear:
        POSTGRES_USER: rails
        POSTGRES_DB: appa_production
      secret:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

In my repo, I have
# master.key
4e4aaaa32d5bd12a846f49a593ca1ccd


# credentials.yml.enc
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--2wgnxUl0INQXAuDv--zjv+cpkH8t39ewgycwh6Hg==

When I run kamal setup I get the following error:

raise ArgumentError, "Missing secret_key_base for '#{Rails.env}' environment, set this string with bin/rails credentials:edit"

When I run  the command above, I get
secret_key_base: fa3247a154a8db696f8d5c0567ac6a345ed078edb141020e79ac3fb8ebc65b985872355719babd30775d8ae04a425330d4a958c8cb6c9dc4a188320277f8971f

To fix the problem, I have to specify the SECRET_KEY_BASE in my deploy file.
env:
  clear:
    POSTGRES_USER: rails
    POSTGRES_HOST: 1.2.3.4
    SECRET_KEY_BASE: fa3247a154a8db696f8d5c0567ac6a345ed078edb141020e79ac3fb8ebc65b985872355719babd30775d8ae04a425330d4a958c8cb6c9dc4a188320277f8971f

All the tutorials/documentation I found don't require specifying the SECRET_KEY_BASE env variable.
Am I missing anything here?

I dont know if its the best idea to expose the master key and credentials of your project ... This problem often happens because he cant find any RAILS_MASTER_KEY. Is you master key on the .env file that kamal is using ?

May be you have the same problem as this issue on github. https://github.com/basecamp/kamal/issues/1273

I had this same issue and I think Rails & Kamal are just not quite up-to-date with each other yet.
I solved it by making a production specific credentials file and telling Kamal the correct key.
Set up the production credential file:
bin/rails credentials:edit --environment production
Adding config/credentials/production.key to store the encryption key: REDACTED

Save this in a password manager your team can access.

If you lose the key, no one, including you, can access anything encrypted with it.

      create  config/credentials/production.key

Ignoring config/credentials/production.key so it won't end up in Git history:

      append  .gitignore

This will put a secret_key_base in the file by default.
Note, it makes a production-specific key, so send it into the Kamal env by updating the secrets:
.kamal/secrets
Change to use the production key.
Before:
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(cat config/master.key)
After:
RAILS_MASTER_KEY=$(cat config/credentials/production.key)
